# Where is the code for a "Windows Runtime Component" located after compilation?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime

When you build a  "Windows Runtime Component" project in Visual Studio 2012, it creates a .winmd and .pri file.

AFAIK, the winmd file contains only metadata, but no code. So where is the actual code located?

EDIT:

Here is the build output, as you can see, there is no mention whatsoever of a dll file:

> 1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: WindowsRuntimeComponent1,
>   Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------ 1>Build started 6/24/2013 1:40:49
>   AM. 1>CoreClean: 1>  Deleting file
>   "C:\test\WindowsRuntimeComponent1\WindowsRuntimeComponent1\bin\Debug\WindowsRuntimeComponent1.winmd".
>   1>  Deleting file
>   "C:\test\WindowsRuntimeComponent1\WindowsRuntimeComponent1\bin\Debug\WindowsRuntimeComponent1.pdb".
>   1>  Deleting file
>   "C:\test\WindowsRuntimeComponent1\WindowsRuntimeComponent1\bin\Debug\WindowsRuntimeComponent1.pri".
>   1>  Deleting file
>   "C:\test\WindowsRuntimeComponent1\WindowsRuntimeComponent1\obj\Debug\WindowsRuntimeComponent1.winmd".
>   1>  Deleting file
>   "C:\test\WindowsRuntimeComponent1\WindowsRuntimeComponent1\obj\Debug\WindowsRuntimeComponent1.pdb".
>   1>  Deleting file
>   "C:\test\WindowsRuntimeComponent1\WindowsRuntimeComponent1\obj\Debug\WindowsRuntimeComponent1.winmdobj".
>   1>  Deleting file
>   "C:\test\WindowsRuntimeComponent1\WindowsRuntimeComponent1\obj\Debug\WindowsRuntimeComponent1.compile.pdb".
>   1>  Deleting file
>   "C:\test\WindowsRuntimeComponent1\WindowsRuntimeComponent1\obj\Debug\priconfig.xml".
>   1>  Deleting file
>   "C:\test\WindowsRuntimeComponent1\WindowsRuntimeComponent1\obj\Debug\layout.resfiles".
>   1>  Deleting file
>   "C:\test\WindowsRuntimeComponent1\WindowsRuntimeComponent1\obj\Debug\resources.resfiles".
>   1>  Deleting file
>   "C:\test\WindowsRuntimeComponent1\WindowsRuntimeComponent1\obj\Debug\pri.resfiles".
>   1>  Deleting file
>   "C:\test\WindowsRuntimeComponent1\WindowsRuntimeComponent1\obj\Debug\LanguageQualifiers.txt".
>   1>GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute: 1>Skipping target
>   "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are
>   up-to-date with respect to the input files. 1>CoreCompile: 1> 
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Csc.exe /noconfig
>   /nowarn:1701,1702,2008
>   /pdb:obj\Debug\WindowsRuntimeComponent1.compile.pdb /nostdlib+
>   /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE;NETFX_CORE
>   /errorendlocation /preferreduilang:en-US /highentropyva+
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\Microsoft.CSharp.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\mscorlib.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Collections.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.ComponentModel.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Core.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Diagnostics.Contracts.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Globalization.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.IO.Compression.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.IO.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Linq.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Linq.Expressions.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Linq.Parallel.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Linq.Queryable.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Net.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Net.Http.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Net.Http.Rtc.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Net.Primitives.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Net.Requests.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Numerics.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.ObjectModel.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Reflection.Context.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Reflection.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Reflection.Extensions.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Reflection.Primitives.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.Numerics.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Security.Principal.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.ServiceModel.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.ServiceModel.Duplex.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.ServiceModel.Http.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.ServiceModel.NetTcp.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.ServiceModel.Primitives.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.ServiceModel.Security.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Text.Encoding.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Threading.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Threading.Tasks.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Windows.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Xml.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Xml.Linq.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Xml.Serialization.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Xml.XDocument.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\8.0\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\Windows.winmd" /debug+
>   /debug:full /filealign:512 /optimize-
>   /out:obj\Debug\WindowsRuntimeComponent1.winmdobj
>   /subsystemversion:6.02 /target:winmdobj /utf8output Class1.cs
>   Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs
>   "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp.NETCore,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
>   obj\Debug\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs
>   obj\Debug\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs
>   obj\Debug\TemporaryGeneratedFile_5937a670-0e60-4077-877b-f7221da3dda1.cs
>   1>ExportWindowsMDFile: 1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\winmdexp.exe
>   /mp:obj\Debug\WindowsRuntimeComponent1.compile.pdb
>   /pdb:obj\Debug\WindowsRuntimeComponent1.pdb
>   /out:obj\Debug\WindowsRuntimeComponent1.winmd /utf8output
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\Microsoft.CSharp.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\mscorlib.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Collections.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.ComponentModel.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Core.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Diagnostics.Contracts.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Globalization.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.IO.Compression.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.IO.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Linq.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Linq.Expressions.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Linq.Parallel.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Linq.Queryable.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Net.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Net.Http.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Net.Http.Rtc.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Net.Primitives.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Net.Requests.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Numerics.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.ObjectModel.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Reflection.Context.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Reflection.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Reflection.Extensions.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Reflection.Primitives.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.Numerics.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Security.Principal.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.ServiceModel.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.ServiceModel.Duplex.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.ServiceModel.Http.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.ServiceModel.NetTcp.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.ServiceModel.Primitives.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.ServiceModel.Security.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Text.Encoding.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Threading.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Threading.Tasks.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Windows.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Xml.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Xml.Linq.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Xml.Serialization.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Xml.XDocument.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\8.0\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\Windows.winmd"
>   obj\Debug\WindowsRuntimeComponent1.winmdobj 
>   1>CopyFilesToOutputDirectory: 1>  Copying file from
>   "obj\Debug\WindowsRuntimeComponent1.winmd" to
>   "bin\Debug\WindowsRuntimeComponent1.winmd". 1>  Copying file from
>   "obj\Debug\WindowsRuntimeComponent1.pdb" to
>   "bin\Debug\WindowsRuntimeComponent1.pdb". 1>  WindowsRuntimeComponent1
>   -> C:\test\WindowsRuntimeComponent1\WindowsRuntimeComponent1\bin\Debug\WindowsRuntimeComponent1.winmd
>   1>GetPackagingOutputs: 1>  WindowsRuntimeComponent1 :
>   WindowsRuntimeComponent1.ProjectPriFile :
>   C:\test\WindowsRuntimeComponent1\WindowsRuntimeComponent1\bin\Debug\WindowsRuntimeComponent1.pri
>   -> WindowsRuntimeComponent1.pri 1>  WindowsRuntimeComponent1 : WindowsRuntimeComponent1.BuiltProjectOutputGroup :
>   C:\test\WindowsRuntimeComponent1\WindowsRuntimeComponent1\bin\Debug\WindowsRuntimeComponent1.winmd
>   -> WindowsRuntimeComponent1.winmd 1>  WindowsRuntimeComponent1 : WindowsRuntimeComponent1.DebugSymbolsProjectOutputGroup :
>   C:\test\WindowsRuntimeComponent1\WindowsRuntimeComponent1\bin\Debug\WindowsRuntimeComponent1.pdb
>   -> WindowsRuntimeComponent1.pdb 1>  WindowsRuntimeComponent1 : WindowsRuntimeComponent1.CopyWinmdArtifactsOutputGroup :
>   C:\test\WindowsRuntimeComponent1\WindowsRuntimeComponent1\bin\Debug\WindowsRuntimeComponent1.winmd
>   -> WindowsRuntimeComponent1.winmd 1>  WindowsRuntimeComponent1 : WindowsRuntimeComponent1.CopyWinmdArtifactsOutputGroup :
>   C:\test\WindowsRuntimeComponent1\WindowsRuntimeComponent1\bin\Debug\WindowsRuntimeComponent1.pdb
>   -> WindowsRuntimeComponent1.pdb 1>  WindowsRuntimeComponent1 : WindowsRuntimeComponent1._GetProjectArchitecture : neutral -> 
>   1>_GenerateProjectPriConfigurationFiles: 1>  WindowsRuntimeComponent1
>   -> obj\Debug\priconfig.xml 1>  WindowsRuntimeComponent1 -> obj\Debug\layout.resfiles 1>  WindowsRuntimeComponent1 ->
>   obj\Debug\resources.resfiles 1>  WindowsRuntimeComponent1 ->
>   obj\Debug\pri.resfiles 1>_GenerateProjectPriFileCore: 1>  C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x86\MakePri.exe New -ProjectRoot
>   C:\test\WindowsRuntimeComponent1\WindowsRuntimeComponent1\ -ConfigXml
>   obj\Debug\priconfig.xml -OutputFile
>   C:\test\WindowsRuntimeComponent1\WindowsRuntimeComponent1\bin\Debug\WindowsRuntimeComponent1.pri
>   -IndexName WindowsRuntimeComponent1 -Verbose -Overwrite   1>  WindowsRuntimeComponent1 -> WindowsRuntimeComponent1.pri 1> 1>Build
>   succeeded. 1> 1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.56
>   ========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the default build setup, you should get a winmd, pri and dll in `$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\$(MSBuildProjectName)\`

Your code will be in the dll

(just confirmed by creating a new WRC using the VS wizard and built)

Comment: I don't see a dll file. I see just the .winmd, .pri, and .pdb file!

Comment: Did you just create a new WRT through the wizard or do you have a custom build setup?

Comment: I created a new WRT through VS's "New Project" dialog. Then I built it and VS showed 1 succeeded, but I cannot find a dll file.

Comment: choose Rebuild and paste the entire build log as an update to your question

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/476957/WINMDplusFilesplusUnderplustheplusHood
 - this seems to indicate that WRT winmd files can contain code.